# Export File : Faces Servlet threw java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

Tags: jsf

I have got a method which exports xls file. The method works correctly but after it's excuted, I get

> Faces Servlet threw java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

Here is the method:

```
public String exportXls() {
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        FacesContext cxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext context = cxt.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getResponse();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=name.xls");
        out = response.getOutputStream();

        WritableWorkbook workbook = createWorkbook(response);

        // All sheets and cells added. Now write out the workbook
        workbook.write();
        workbook.close(); 
        System.out.println("XLS written!");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("ERROR OCCURRED WITH exportXls" + ex.toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) out.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "page";
}
```

I have closed the `OutputStream` and `Workbook`. What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: For future JSF questions, please use `[jsf]` tag. Do not use `[servlets]` tag if you aren't extending the `HttpServlet` class yourself. Do not use `[jsp]` tag if the problem is purely caused by the backing bean, not by the JSP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell JSF that you've already completed the response by calling [`FacesContext#resposneComplete()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29). You should also not return a navigation case string (not that it would harm, but that's entirely superfluous and confusing for the maintainer).

```
public void exportXls() {
    // ...

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I strongly recommend to *remove* the `catch (Exception ex)` block and replace it by a `throws IOException` on the method. All that code can throw is an `IOException`. You shouldn't swallow that exception, but let the container handle it. This also allows for a more centralized exception logging by a `Filter`.

Comment: Thanks very much BalusC :) . Your solution is exactly what I need. BTW apologies about the wrong tag.

Comment: You're welcome. No problem about the tags, for everyone it's ever the first time. Luckily everyone with sufficient reps can correct it for you here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot forward (or redirect) once there's been content output to the client.

What you're trying to do would be equivalent to getting two responses back for a single request-you can get a file back, or a new page, but not both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dave. What would you suggest me to do in this case? I tried to excuted it without "return" to the current page but it produced the same exception. Many thanks.

Comment: Dave wouldn't know that as he don't use JSF. He was just translating the exception in layman's terms so that you should have a better insight of what's happening under the covers (and thus should already know the possible solution yourself if you were more familiar with the JSF API).

Comment: @BalusC Correction; I use it as little as possible :)

Comment: So, you have *ever* used it? Oh the horror!

Comment: @BalusC No kidding ;) With current JEE, it's really not that bad. But don't tell anybody I said that.